# Raycaster missing half a plane in three.js - bug?

Tags: three.js

In order to stretch a 2D rounded rectangle without distortion, I repositioned the rectangle towards one direction (eg left) by the desired amount and added that amount to the right-most vertices to compensate and appear stretched.
The problem is that now raycaster is missing the right-half of the rectangle.

```
I made the following jsfiddle stretching a normal rectangle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vser1n2u/5/
If you hover the mouse on the rectangle you’ll see that raycaster works properly (“TRUE” indication). If you click on the rectangle, it will expand to the left. Now if you hover you’ll see that it works only half way (“FALSE” indication).

Am I missing something, or is this a three.js bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify the vertices of a geometry after it has been rendered, you need to recompute the bounding sphere for raycasting and frustum culling to work correctly.

So in your case,

```
o.m.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vser1n2u/6/

three.js r.98

Comment: Ironically, I tried that a while ago, I considered it my last chance, but I placed it *before* the verticesNeedUpdate so it didn't work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Correction: I used computeBoundingBox.